# TypeError: posts.map is not a function in Reactjs while fetching data from an API using useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I am getting the below error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJiem.png)

import React ,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function DataFetching() {

```
const[posts,setPosts]= useState([])

useEffect(()=>{

    axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    .then(res=>{

        console.log(res)
        setPosts(res.data)
    })
    .catch(err=>
        console.log(err) )

},[])
return (
    <div>
      
        <ul>
            {
          **  posts.map(post=><li key={post.id}>{post.email}</li>)**
            }
        </ul>
        
    </div>
);
```

}

export default DataFetching;

Data is successfully store in hook but map function getting an error: Posts.map is not a function

I have tried Object.values(posts).map but it  is not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to implement your data fetching as below. Hope it works.

```
  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users');
        if (response.status === 200) {
          const data = response.data;
          console.log(data);
          setPosts(data);
        } else {
          throw new Error('Network error occured.');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error occured while fetching data: ', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-19hl8o?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried as suggested. but it doesn't work.  It shows  'The above error occurred in <DataFetching>' component. But no details about the error